# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jxl.read.biff.BiffException

Tags: java, excel, jxl, classnotfound

In my J2EE web project, I have a simple JSP (HomeScreen.jsp) and a servlet class (HomeScreenServlet.java) behind it. This class is calling non-static method (PDFAwt1) from another class (PDFAwt) which in turn calls many other methods from many different classes, as usually happens.

**When I try to create an object of the PDFAwt to call PDFAwt1()**, I get an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jxl.read.biff.BiffException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1360)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1206)
...
```

Here is a little preview of PDFAwt1()

```
CreateExcelFile cef = new CreateExcelFile();

ImageConversion.setupPDFToPNG(ReferencePath);
ImageConversion.setupPDFToPNG(NewPath);

File folder = new File(ReferencePath + "/png");
File[] f = folder.listFiles();
File folder1 = new File(NewPath + "/png");
File[] f1 = folder1.listFiles();
...
```

CreateExcelFile()

```
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.format.Colour;
...
public class CreateExcelFile {
  public CreateExcelFile() {
    try {
      if (!new File("LabelsTemplate.xls").exists()) {
        WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("LabelsTemplate.xls"));
        WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1", 0);
        ... 
    }
  }
}
```

Not able to find where the problem is exactly.. please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing jar in your class path, if you are using any `IDE`, download the respective jar and set it in your build path before running the application. 
In case you are not using any IDE, add the respective jar's to the `lib` folder of your `web application`.

Comment: I have already added all the required JARs in the build path and I am using Eclipse Galileo.

Comment: Problem solved. I only referenced all the JARs in Java Build Path but now I manually added those JARs to the WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder, and everything is back on track. New to Java thats why these kinda mistakes. Thanks for the hint. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is transitively dependent on some `jars` and you are missing those on your classpath. `Maven` is a good tool to avoid such transitive dependencies. If you are not using maven then you need to find the `jars` that you are using, required what all other `jars`. As a first step, try to find the jar which contains the follwing class:

```
jxl.read.biff.BiffException
```

Comment: This exception is there in jxl-2.6.jar and I have added it in Java Build Path of my project.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BiffException extends JXLException
```

Exception thrown when reading a biff file

This exception has a number of messages that should provide some information about the cause:

```
excelFileNotFound        
excelFileTooBig         
expectedGlobals         
passwordProtected         
streamNotFound         
unrecognizedBiffVersion
unrecognizedOLEFile
```

Print the message to see exact problem.

You can find missing jar [here](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/jxl.read.biff.BiffException)

As the name suggests `ClassNotFoundException` in Java is a subclass of `java.lang.Exception` and Comes when **Java Virtual Machine** tries to load a particular class and **doesn't found the requested class in classpath.**

Another important point about this Exception is that, It is a **checked Exception** and you need to provide explicitly Exception handling while using methods which can possibly throw `ClassNotFoundException` in java either by using try-catch block or by using throws clause.

[Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html)

```
public class ClassNotFoundException
 extends ReflectiveOperationException
```

Thrown when an application tries to load in a class through its string name using:

- The forName method in class Class.
- The findSystemClass method in class ClassLoader .
- The loadClass method in class ClassLoader.

but no definition for the class with the specified name could be found.